# QDataWidgetMapper и QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Пытаюсь использовать `QDataWidgetMapper` совместно с `QComboBox`, который должен выводить строки из табличной модели, находящиеся в колонке `name`, но при этом оперировать значениями из колонки `id`. Таблица имеет наименование `workers`.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "crmmodel.h"

model = new CRMModel(this,baze);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(model->fieldIndex("name")
    , new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->tableView));

typeIndex = model->fieldIndex("name");
relModel = new QSqlTableModel;
relModel = model->relationModel(typeIndex);

new_o = new newOrder();
new_o->setParent(this,Qt::Window);   
new_o->setModel(model, relModel);
```

**crmmodel.cpp**

```
CRMModel::CRMModel(QObject *parent, QSqlDatabase db)
    : QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent, db) { 

    setTable("orders");
    setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel::LeftJoin); 
    setRelation(fieldIndex("worker_id")
        , QSqlRelation("workers","worker_id","name"));
    setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    select();
}
```

**neworder.cpp**

```
mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
mapper->setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::ManualSubmit);

void newOrder::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model
    , QSqlTableModel *relModel) {

    mapper->setModel(model);
    mapper->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(this));

    ui->workerComboBox->setModel(relModel);
    ui->workerComboBox->setModelColumn(relModel->fieldIndex("name"));

    mapper->addMapping(ui->adressLineEdit,1);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->orderTextEdit,2,"plainText");
    mapper->addMapping(ui->phoneLineEdit,3);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->phone2LineEdit,4);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->execDateEdit,6);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->timeEdit,7);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->timeEdit_2,8);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->salarySpinBox,9);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->workerComboBox
        , relModel->fieldIndex("name"));   
}
```

Вызов `model->select();` все показывает, но непосредственного сохранения данных по `model->submitAll()` не происходит. Вероятно, в БД вместо идентификаторов отправляются имена.

Comment: почему после добавления этого комбобокса перестали данные из первой модели (model) отправятся?

Comment: проблема очень актуальна. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

В Qt имеется [пример](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-sqlwidgetmapper-example.html) на эту тему. Вся прелесть в том, что если его собрать и запустить, то будет наблюдаться ровно такая же неадекватность, что описана в вопросе. Связана она со стратегией редактирования модели. Если оставить принятую по умолчанию `QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit`, то как не меняй значения в раскрывающемся списке, изменения к таблице не применятся. При этом ещё более удручает то, что добавление ручного вызова `submitAll()` также не выручает. Если же изменить стратегию редактирования модели на `QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange` (значение `QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange` не помогает решить проблему), то всё работает как положено.

Comment: у меня наверное совсем тяжелый случай. не помогло :(

Comment: Сравнивайте свой код с этим примером и ищите разницу. Где-то, может быть, что-то лишнее добавили, а где-то, может, чего-то не хватает.

Comment: model->submitAll();   выдает false. я уже все что можно перепробовал. Брутфорс уже начался....) Христа ради ...спасите)